# Issue with saving the plotted data in JRI

Tags: r, plot, jri

```
re.eval("cpu_plot <- function (fore) {;plot(fore, xaxt=\"n\", main=\"Forecast and Plot for the CPU Utilization\", xlab=\"Month\", ylab=\"CPU Utilization\");a = seq(as.Date(\"2015-01-01\"), by=\"months\", length=13);axis(1, at = decimal_date(a), labels = format(a, \"%Y %b\"), cex.axis=0.6);abline(v = decimal_date(a), col='grey', lwd=0.5);segments(2015.58,fore.auto.arima$x[8],2015.67,fore.auto.arima$mean[1], col=\"black\");}");
```

Same custom function if I create in RStudio and plot the graph, it is plotting successfully and using below I am able to save as a pdf.

```
dev.print(pdf, 'img.pdf')
```

But when same save command called from JSP, it is not doing any additional tasks which are called by my custom function like, "axis, abline, segments". Only the plot part is getting saved by below command.

```
re.eval("dev.print(pdf, '/Users/ashianan/Pics/img.pdf')");
```

Comment: Can you please attach all of the .Java file?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't call `pdf("img.pdf");cpu_plot(...);dev.off()`? You don't even know if you have a usable default device, so why don't you plot directly in the device you actually want to use (here `pdf()`)? That's much less error-prone and it won't require R to plot twice...